# parse from .csv to mapbox map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, read.csv, parsefloat

I'm building my wife a map of accessible toilets in Australia. the data is available as a .csv and I am using async/await fetch to access the data. when i try to pass my lat and lon variables into the mapbox setLongLat() method i get a NaN.

i thought that it may be a datatype issue, but if I wrap lat and lng in ParseFLoat, it still returns NaN.

could someone please point out where i have gone wrong and help me refine my very primitive code...? perhaps also show me how to clean the data properly and create proper error handling...?

i'll reset the free API key when i get an answer

Andy :)

```js
// import possible due to type="module"attribute in html script tag
import 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js';

// create a variable to hold the API key
const mapToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3R1ZGlvcHJvamVjdHMiLCJhIjoiY2t3djUyeHhpMDJpaTJ2c2VoZWE0b3BtbSJ9.YOluxDwyY0oUTvf0Y8ec1Q';

mapboxgl.accessToken = mapToken; // pass in the API key

let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
  zoom: 10,
  center: [200, -20]
});

async function getData() {
  const response = fetch('assets/smaller.csv');
  const data = await (await response).text();

  const table = data.split('\n').slice(1) // get rid of the first row of the CSV using the slice method
  table.forEach(row => {
    const columns = row.split(','); // get rid of the delimiter using the split method

    const name = columns[2];
    const facType = columns[3];
    const address = columns[4];
    const town = columns[5];
    const state = columns[6];
    const lat = columns[8];
    const lng = columns[9];

    console.log(name, lat, lng);

    new mapboxgl.Marker({
      draggable: true
    }).setLngLat([lng, lat]).addTo(map);


  })
}

getData();
```

here is part of the .CSV file...

```html
"FacilityID","URL","Name","FacilityType","Address1","Town","State","AddressNote","Latitude","Longitude","Parking","ParkingAccessible","ParkingNote","KeyRequired","MLAK24","MLAKAfterHours","PaymentRequired","AccessNote","AdultChange","ChangingPlaces","BYOSling","ACShower","ACMLAK","AdultChangeNote","BabyChange","BabyCareRoom","BabyChangeNote","DumpPoint","DPWashout","DPAfterHours","DumpPointNote","OpeningHours","OpeningHoursNote","Male","Female","Unisex","AllGender","Ambulant","Accessible","LHTransfer","RHTransfer","ToiletNote","SharpsDisposal","DrinkingWater","SanitaryDisposal","MensPadDisposal","Shower"

"1","https://toiletmap.gov.au/facility/1","Sandy Beach Reserve","Park or reserve","West Road","Bassendean","WA","","-31.92183600","115.95020622","False","False","","False","False","False","False","","False","False","False","False","False","","False","False","","False","False","False","","OPEN: 24 hours","","True","True","False","False","False","True","False","False","","True","False","False","False","True"

"2","https://toiletmap.gov.au/facility/2","Point Reserve","Park or reserve","North Road","Bassendean","WA","","-31.90441010","115.96099110","False","False","","False","False","False","False","","False","False","False","False","False","","False","False","","False","False","False","","OPEN: Daylight hours","","True","True","False","False","False","True","False","False","","False","False","False","False","False"

"3","https://toiletmap.gov.au/facility/3","Success Hill Reserve","Park or reserve","Off Seventh Avenue","Bassendean","WA","","-31.89628865","115.95578101","True","True","","False","False","False","False","","False","False","False","False","False","","True","False","","False","False","False","","OPEN: Daylight hours","","True","True","False","False","False","True","False","False","","True","True","False","False","True"
```

Comment: As a security necessity, you should NEVER post your API key publicly. You should immediately remove that API key from this post and invalidate this key and generate a new one. Otherwise, people can make API requests on your account which costs you money.

Comment: sorry, i'm aware of that and will change it in an hour or so :)